# Reading in Columns from a text file Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large .txt file (many GB) in the the format:

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4
|"text"|"text"|"text"|"text"
|"text"|"text"|"text"|"text"
```

I would like to read this data straight into a pandas dataframe. Is this possible with a pandas command e.g.

```
df = pd.read_XXX()
```

If not with pandas, can someone advise on how to read in a file of this type? I am not familiar with this format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.pd.read_csv` like this

`df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt', sep = '|')`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a `csv` file (comma seperated value).

You read this file in pandas with:

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep='|')`